# Delphi - How to return different types from a function

Tags: function, delphi, variant

Delphi Rio - I am writing a class, where one of the functions is AddFilter.  When the AddFilter class is executed, depending on various factors it will either create a filter, or create a slicer. (Think of Excel Filters and Slicers).  I want the function to return the newly created object, which is either tFilterElement, or tSlicerElement, which are separate, non-related classes. My challenge is how do I have a function which can return a newly created object; which can be one of 2 different classes?  I am trying to use Variants here, but I cannot get this to work.  Pseudo Code is

```
function TPivotTable.addFilter(params...):Variant;
var
E1 : tFilterElement;
E2 : tSlicerElement;

begin

... if this can be a Filter
E1 := TFilterElement.Create(params);
result := E1;

... else
E2 := TSlicerElement.Create; 
result := E2;
 
end;
```

I have tried

```
result := E1 as Variant;
```

as well as

```
result := Variant(E1);
```

But neither work.  Is there a way to do this? I am not tied to Variants, I just couldn't think of any other approach that might work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always declare the result type as `TObject`, or any other common ancestor of both `TFilterElement` and `TSlicerElement`:

```
function TPivotTable.AddFilter(...): TObject;
begin
  if SomeCondition then
    Result := TFilterElement.Create
  else
    Result := TSlicerElement.Create;
end;
```

When you use this function, you must then investigate the result and see what class it is:

```
MyThing := MyPivotTable.AddFilter(...);
if MyThing is TFilterElement then
  TFilterElement(MyThing).DoSomeFilterStuff
else if MyThing is TSlicerElement then
  TSlicerElement(MyThing).DoSomeSlicerStuff
else
  raise Exception.Create('Neither a filter nor a slicer was returned.');
```

All this being said, this seems like a rather poor design. (All `is` checks and casting is a sign of this.)

I don't know your application, but maybe you could create a class `TElement` with `TFilterElement` and `TSlicerElement` as descendant classes?

Comment: @@Andreas - that worked, but I then have to cast my return based on TFilterElement or TSlicerElement.  I can do this...Can you explain WHY my Variant approach is not working?

Comment: @user1009073: [Variants](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Variant_Types_(Delphi)) cannot hold objects. (See the second paragraph.)

Comment: @user1009073: If you find that you write a block of code that contains `TFilterElement(MyThing)` many times, it is a good idea to declare a variable of type `TFilterElement` -- `MyFilter`, say -- and assign the object to this variable: `MyFilter := TFilterElement(MyThing)`. Then you can use `MyFilter` at every later occurrence. (But only do this after you have verified that `MyThing` really is a `TFilterElement`.) You could also use the `absolute` keyword.

Comment: How about using an interface?